# Does maven-checkstyle-plugin checks files only within the /src directory

Tags: java, api, maven, configuration, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I wonder if the maven-checkstyle-plugin only check files within the /src directories of a project or multi-module project.

I do have a maven project where I don't have /src directories but loads of *.yaml, *.wsdl, *.json and *.xsd files and do not know if they are gonna checked with this plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can activate more checks for more filetypes in more locations. However...

You are probably using the [`check` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html) of the maven-checkstyle-plugin. As you can see, the default resource includes is only set to `**/*.properties`. Change it to anything you like.

---

To answer your seconds question, where checkstyle will look for sources and resources, there's an option for this in the same page:

```
<sourceDirectories> List    2.13    Specifies the location of the source directories to be used for Checkstyle. Default value is ${project.compileSourceRoots}.
```

However, [the standard checks included in checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks.html) do not include a lot of checks for files other than `.java` or `.properties` files. You might want to take a look at other plugins, like [the spotless-maven-plugin's prettier](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven#prettier) configuration.